# Best way to Shift along a Multi Index Time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that contains option data. For each element I have a current date and an expiration date. I have a two-level Multi index that looks like:

```
                  symbol exchange  adjusted stock close price  \
date     expiration                                               
01/31/90 02/17/90      SPX     CBOE                      329.08   
         02/17/90      SPX     CBOE                      329.08   
         02/17/90      SPX     CBOE                      329.08   
         02/17/90      SPX     CBOE                      329.08   
         02/17/90      SPX     CBOE                      329.08   
......
...... 
......
                    symbol exchange  adjusted stock close price  \
date     expiration                                               
02/14/14 12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63
```

There are other columns, but for example's sake they are irrelevant. What I am trying to do, and I might just be unclear on the shifting documents, is to shift all of the data down or up by the first level index. So shift all of the data from the next date index up to the previous date index. So if there were no other dates in between the example, I would like a DataFrame that looks like:

```
                  symbol exchange  adjusted stock close price  \
date     expiration                                               
01/31/90 12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
         12/16/16      SPX     CBOE                     1838.63   
......
.......
.......
                    symbol exchange  adjusted stock close price  \
date     expiration                                               
02/14/14 THIS WOULD HAVE NaN data because it's the last set
```

Does this make any sense? The idea is to shift all of the data up a period to compute change in prices.

Comment: Try using the [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method as Wes suggests [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180499/most-efficient-way-to-shift-multiindex-time-series?rq=1)

Comment: I tried that method and I get a duplicate index error. But I'm quite certain that I don't have any duplicated date entries.         raise ReshapeError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
pandas.core.reshape.ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape    . this is raised on the unstack part of the function

Comment: Why don't you just shift the date and merge it? d = pd.Series(df.date.unique()); df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : d, 'next' : d.shift(1)}); pd.merge(<your DF>, df, on='date', how='left')

Comment: Wouldn't that just give me a shifted dates set, wouldn't it give me the original df with a shifted date column / index ? I needed to shift all of the information. Maybe however, I can have a shifted index as you show, copy the dataframe, reindex by the shifted one and then join it and drop the new index? I'll try it and see.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post data that demonstrates the problem? It's really hard to tell you why some solutions aren't working when we can't replicate the problem.